# Integral of a square wave

Tags: integration

Hello guys I have a small question :)

Why is the integral of a square wave with $50$% duty cycle, centered at $0$ not equal to $0$?

The integral is over a period (from $0$ to $2\pi$):

from $0$ to $\pi$ : $f(wt) = Vp$

from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ : $f(wt) = -Vp$

I mean a sine wave with these properties have an integral of $0$.
So why is the square wave's integral the area under the wave over half a period?

[This is the image of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm5ed.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume you are taking the integral from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Over what interval are you integrating? And if you're doing an infinite interval, you're considering Cauchy principal value?

Comment: Can you provide the integral?

Comment: it's over a period (from 0 to 2pi) and the square wave has a peak of Vi and -Vi

Comment: You make it unnecessarily difficult for people to help by not explaining the function better. If you cannot write an analytical expression for the function (which should be possible), then maybe you can draw the graph of it?

Comment: i posted a picture

Comment: The integral over a full period ($T$) of what you show in the image is zero. Maybe there is some other source of confusion. Is this your original problem?

Comment: actually it is :p because we always take the area under the curve of the first part (from 0 to T/2) so i got confused